# Disappear text when button is clicked (JQUERY)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

So I am making a small PHP Javascript and JQUERY Chatbox and so far its working pretty good but im trying to "Fancy it up".  It asks you, the user, for your Name and once you type your name in to the input box you are supposed to click Enter which brings you to the chat box.  Here is the code for the Chatbox.

http://pastebin.com/DgQEC9rV
You can find the Send button in the PHP at the top of the page.

But I was wondering how to make the Send button and the whole box it is in disappear with JQUERY and have the chat box still load in regularly.

A live example of the chat right now. --> http://www.carlosmayers.com/knil/chat/

I know just looking at the code might make this question seem very unapproachable but I know someone here can help me!  Thanks.

Comment: You can put together a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) if looking at the code is so unapproachable

Answer (score 0):

If i intepreted your question right you just want to hide the hole chatbox. But it should still update itself.

So with jQuery you do this: `$("#wrapper").attr("style", "display: none");`

Whereas `#wrapper` is the div with the id (# := css-Selector) "wrapper" in your document.

jQuery now sets its `style` to `"display: none"`, but the Chatbox will still be updated!

If you have Chrome, feel free to test it in the console first.

You could also use `$("#wrapper").hide();`

Comment: You should use `$.hide()` better.